# stop the background scrolling when the pushbar is open in react js

Tags: reactjs

In react js when i click the pushbar icon ,the pushbar has been opened ,but the background of pushbar(i mean hole body of content) is scrolling, i want to stop the background scroll, so any one please help me ,thanks in advance

Comment: Please vist [How to ask good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and elaborate your question by adding code.

Comment: Provide us with the code you have tried. It seems like you have to use an event listener on the pushbar so it manipulates css or javascript (whatever you use to scroll the background) so when it is opened the background stops scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

It is not react issue. Moreover, try adding `overflow: hidden` to body tag when pushbar is opened and reset `overflow: auto` when pushbar is closed.

Comment: i dont know how to add overflow:hidden when pushbar is opened or closed